# Powershell Get-childitem script not saves output on Windows 10 machines or when pushed remotely

Tags: powershell

I have written a simple script that should collect all local documents from folders on C: drive (*.pdf, *.jpg, *.xls, *.doc) and save them to the "computername" text file under the `C:\TEMP` folder.

I have been able to launch this locally on Windows 11 machine without issues! When I tried to do the same thing on Windows 10 machine text file was empty!

I have narrow this down to the user account interaction, as it seems on Windows 10 machines. If this script is launched from PowerShell running as current user on Windows 10 it seems the script generates output. If it is Run as Administrator (locally or via remote push as admin) I got empty file.  I would appreciate any guidance.

code:

```
    $FindDate=(Get-Date).adddays(-180)
    [System.IO.Directory]::CreateDirectory('C:\TEMP')
    {Get-ChildItem -Path C:\ -Directory} |
    Where-Object Name -NotIn @('Windows','Program Files','$Recycle.Bin','Windows.old') |
    % { Get-ChildItem -Include *.doc,*.docx,*.pdf,*.jpg,*jpeg,*.xls,*.xlsx -File - 
    Recurse} -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
    Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -ge $FindDate } |
    Select LastWriteTime,Name,Directory | 
    Out-File C:\TEMP\$env:Computername.txt
```

Comment: Removing `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` might provide some useful feedback.  You're also not making use of the current directory in the pipeline (`$_` variable) inside of your `ForEach-Object` (`%`) scriptblock.  A minor recommendation, but I would use `(Get-Date).Date.AddDays(-180)` so `$FindDate` is always _midnight_ of 180 days ago and you don't get different results because you ran the script at, say, 3 PM instead of 9 AM.

Comment: You also have a typo in your `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet, there's an extra space `- Recurse`

Answer (score 1):

there are some issues with the current code:

e.g. you do:

```
{Get-ChildItem -Path C:\ -Directory}
```

this defines a expression and will not execute:

```
PS C:\Users\vcxy> {Get-ChildItem -Path C:\ -Directory}
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\ -Directory
PS C:\Users\vcxy>
```

you want probably:

```
    PS C:\Users\vcxy> Get-ChildItem -Path C:\ -Directory


    Directory: C:\


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----         8/15/2022   2:46 PM                AMD
d-----          6/5/2021   2:10 PM                PerfLogs
d-----         4/19/2022   6:56 PM                plc_debug
d-r---         9/22/2022   6:26 PM                Program Files
d-r---         6/12/2022   5:02 PM                Program Files (x86)
d-----         9/27/2022   6:43 PM                TEMP
d-----         9/27/2022   5:06 PM                tmp
d-r---         10/6/2021  12:44 PM                Users
d-----          4/8/2020   2:18 PM                VM
d-----         9/22/2022  10:46 PM                Windows
```

I'll updated your version as needed:

```
$FindDate=(Get-Date).adddays(-180)
#This works but you could also do new-item C:\temp -ItemType Directory
[System.IO.Directory]::CreateDirectory('C:\TEMP')
$folders = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\ -Directory | Where-Object {$_.Name -Notmatch 'Windows|Program Files|$Recycle\.Bin|Windows\.old'}
$files = @(
    $folders | % { 
        Get-ChildItem -Path $_.fullname -Include *.doc,*.docx,*.pdf,*.jpg,*jpeg,*.xls,*.xlsx -File -Recurse -ErrorAction:SilentlyContinue | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -ge $FindDate} 
    }
)
#You should use export-csv, its better for later processing of the data
If ($files){
    $files | Select LastWriteTime,Name,Directory | export-csv C:\TEMP\$env:Computername.txt
}
```

It will only create the output file if files are found, no files no output file or in regards to the original version, no files no content in the output file.

Comment: I think making `Export-Csv` conditional with `If ($files) {` is problematic because an empty output file makes clear the script completed and there were no results, whereas a missing output file could mean there were no results or an error occurred.  Also, if the output file still remains from a previous run the old, obsolete results would be left behind instead of overwriting with new, empty results.  This way also requires buffering the complete collection of files as well.

Comment: it depends... I would go the route to write only a file if content is there to write. but probably the best would be to push the command from a central point to the machines and collect the information centrally... but anyways I fixed the bugs in the code and if he wants a file in any case it is not that hard to modify it...

Comment: Hi Tony,  Your script worked and worked also remotely!!! Many Thanks!

Comment: I would like to learn something here though. To your initial note that I did this {Get-ChildItem -Path C:\ -Directory} so create expression not a function this was probably lost somewhere in translation as I have it without the quotes. What was odd was that the whole script ran fine on Windows 11. I couldn't make it work on the Windows 10 unless I did launch it via PS ISE Editor. It would not work at all if launch it via cmd with -file parameter. Can you elaborate on what was the issue with this definition of array: Where-Object Name -NotIn @('Windows','Program Files','$Recycle.Bin','Windows.o

Comment: there was no isssue with your where statement. Had more to do with how I write code ;-) you had the expression issue as already explained and "-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue" is not inside the curly brackets. piping is nice but as in your example you can easy lose oversight...